# Add button onmouseover over any image

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP "`while` loop" list that displays images by using the `img` tag. That works perfectly.

Now, I want to create a JavaScript function that will show a button when the user hovers over any image with the mouse. The problem is that I want to show the button **over the image** when the mouse is 'hovered' on.

See example below:

[image: Example of what it should look like]

How can I do this?

Comment: `img:hover + button{ display: block; }`

Comment: Did you try using the CSS --> position:absolute on image and button?

Comment: Just to clarify, in the example image above the buttons are only partially covering the bottom quarter of the image, right? (the top 3/4 are the image itself?)

Comment: yes this is what i want.

Comment: Can you write the function for me? 
img:hover + button{ display: block; }
Thats too little info for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS:

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:380px;
    height:inherit;
    float:left;
}
.container div.item {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#999;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px red solid;
}
.container div.item a {
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    border:1px red solid;
}
.container div.item:hover a {
    display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><img src="smallimage.png" /><a id="img1" href="javascript:largerimg(this);">View Larger</a></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="smallimage.png" /><a id="img2" href="javascript:largerimg(this);">View Larger</a></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="smallimage.png" /><a id="img3" href="javascript:largerimg(this);">View Larger</a></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="smallimage.png" /><a id="img4" href="javascript:largerimg(this);">View Larger</a></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="smallimage.png" /><a id="img5" href="javascript:largerimg(this);">View Larger</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and the javascript function?

Comment: You don't need javascript function for just showing a button on hover. you can add any lightbox code to show larger image.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a css animation with jquery to show the buttons.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/xGFTB/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div img").on('mouseover', function () {
        $("span").animate({
            'top': 0
        });
    });
    $("div img").on('mouseout', function () {
        $("span").animate({
            'top': 50
        });
    });
});
```